# Setting Variable to Command Output in ansible/jinja2 Variable file

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I am creating a configfile in ansible from a jinja2 template for different deployment enviornments. For this i have a yaml file for every enviornment, which Looks like this:

```
Serverip: 127.0.0.1
Login:
  Username: Rudolf
  Password: rudolfssecret
```

Now, for some environments I want to put certain variables in a vault and extract them using a Command Line Tool (like [this one](https://gitlab.com/wintercloud/keepass-cli)).

This could be done by getting the values from the vault and combining them with the variables File somehow. But this way the seceret variables would be removed completly from the variables File. Somone seeing the Files could think that These variables are Missing or do not exist.

I would prefer somethig like this:

```
Serverip: 127.0.0.1
Login:
  Username: Rudolf
  Password: {{shell: keepass-cli extract-value -f keepassfile -name Password}}
```

So when ansible loads the variables from the file, it fills that value with the Output of the shell Command.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer [Playbook Best Practices – Variables and Vaults](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_best_practices.html#best-practices-for-variables-and-vaults) for that matter.

> ...create two files named `vars` and `vault`. Inside of the `vars` file, define all of the variables needed, including any sensitive ones. Next, copy all of the sensitive variables over to the `vault` file and prefix these variables with `vault_`. You should adjust the variables in the `vars` file to point to the matching `vault_` variables and ensure that the `vault` file is vault encrypted.

If you prefer externals password management tools instead of vault, you can still follow this advice.
In you case define vars file as follows:

```
Serverip: 127.0.0.1
Login:
  Username: Rudolf
  Password: "{{ encrypted_password }}"
```

And during playbook execution ensure that `encrypted_password` is fetched from your password management tool.